# Razor Component interfaces

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, .net-5

Is it possible to define and implement razor component interfaces?

I guess I would imagine something like the following for components (I'm aware this isn't valid code)

**IWelcomeComponent.razor**

```
@code
{
  [Parameter]
  public string Name;
}
```

**WelcomeComponentA.razor**

```
@implements IWelcomeComponent

<div>
  Hello @Name!
</div>
@code
{
  [Parameter]
  public string Name;
}
```

**WelcomeComponentB.razor**

```
@implements IWelcomeComponent

<div>
  Welcome @Name!
</div>
@code
{
  [Parameter]
  public string Name;
}
```

Why would I like this? Per install display changes. Ideally I would like to be able to define which type of components get used via config, similar to how I do this when defining which `IEmailService` I want to use.

```
switch (configuration.GetValue<string>("EmailProvider"))
{
    case "Mock":
        services.AddScoped<IEmailService, MockEmailService>();
        break;
    case "Smtp":
        services.AddScoped<IEmailService, SmtpEmailService>();
        services.Configure<SmtpConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("SmtpConfiguration"));
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("appsettings.json EmailProvider must be set. Use 'Mock' to send emails to console log");
}
```

so if I wanted to implement `WelcomeComponentB` I would have something that lets me state "hey, when I say IWelcomeComponent I want you to show WelcomeComponentB", again I'm aware this isn't remotely correct but something like...

```
services.AddScoped<IWelcomeComponent, WelcomeComponentB>();
```

and then within my razor pages, each `IWelcomeComponent` would render as a `WelcomeComponentB`

e.g.

```
<IWelcomeComponent Name="Chris"/>
```

would render as

```
<div>
  Welcome Chris!
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: you can use the RenderTreeBuilder to build RenderFragments dynamically...

Comment: If you define a class that holds the parameters.
You can create a RenderFragment<T> for each type where T is the parameter class. Then you call the Renderfragment of your choice passing the same parameter. Remember renderfragments are delegetes..

Answer (score 1):

1. You can extend from `ComponentBase` for component blazor component inheritance. Additionally, it can implement interfaces
2. Check out the new experimental `DynamicComponent` if you want truly dynamic type-driven component polymorphism.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0

However, I am not sure the idea of injecting a blazor component is valid. You cannot inject a blazor component as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you searching for something like this, but I used it in an similar  situation as you described

```
@CreateComponent();

@code {

    private RenderFragment CreateComponent() => builder =>
    {   
        builder.OpenElement(0, "p", implementedBySomething.YourString);
        builder.ElementClose();    
    };
}
```

Like this you can render everything at runtime